# GNU CC and Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw, gnu

I'm a bit confused about the options for using GNU CC on Windows.

If I want to primarily develop console applications (as opposed to GUI apps) what do I need? Where do Cygwin and MinGW figure? For example, if I use the NetBeans IDE C/C++ option, that requires installation of Cygwin.

Are there any options which would allow Console application development without Cygwin?

Answer (score 3):

Both MinGW & Cygwin give you the gcc compiler but if you use MinGW you don't need to install Cygwin because it uses native Windows libraries rather than Cygwin libraries

Cygwin is more than just compilers, it tries to provide a UNIX programming environment by building a lot of UNIX libraries on top of Windows SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You could install CodeBlocks IDE oder DevCPP ide. If you do not require special posix api's then you do not need to install cygwin.

Comment: Thx. I have been trying out Code::Blocks

Answer (score 1):

You really really should check out Visual C++ Express. It makes developing on windows A LOT easier. I it is free and the Visual C++ is the preferred way to develop windows apps. ANd yes, you can make console applications too.

Comment: Byron: my understanding was that the VC++ Express edition was not very conformant to C99

Comment: Joakim: my understanding was that the VC++ Express edition was not very conformant to C99

Answer (score 1):

That clarifies things. I'm not particularly interested in a *nix-like environment. I was more interested in getting a GNU C compiler that conforms closely with C99 (which I believe the latest GCC compiler does) and using it as a C learning exercise (hence console rather than GUI apps)

It appears to me that NetBeans IDE/Cygwin option installs an earlier version of the compiler.

So, it appears that MinGW is what I am looking for if I want to use GNU C. Incidentally, the free Pelles C compiler/IDE has a very full C99 implementation.

Comment: You should comment on your question using the comment function.

Comment: My apologies for not adhering to protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vc express for concole apps if you wish, or really any compiler for win platform.

Comment: Joakim: my understanding was that the VC++ Express edition was not very conformant to C99

Comment: You didn't mention C99 in your question (and your answer where posted after mine), anyway I got no idea about that

Answer (score 0):

MinGW can support many languages as well as GNU C Compiler. It also comes with msys package that you can simulate UNIX environment. Cygwin does the same thing as msys does. I'd advice you to install MinGW with full msys support.